# Object Required on Copy Paste from Different Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, object, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy a range from a sheet and then transpose + paste it into another sheet in the same workbook but for some reason am getting an

> object required error

on the initial `.Copy` line. Could someone explain this to me?

```
Sub Clean()
    Dim tRow As Double
    Dim bRow As Double
    Dim PasteRange As Double

    tRow = 5

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian").Activate
        bRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        Worksheets("Canadian").Range(.Cells(tRow, "A"), .Cells(bRow, "A")).Copy
        PasteRange = (bRow - tRow)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SectorSort").Activate
        .Range(.Cells(7, "D"), .Cells(7, PasteRange + 4)).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues), Transpose:=True    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `.Activate` and declare your variables as `Long`.

Comment: Perfect, it worked. With regards to the paste values...is it possible to format them as dates?

Comment: Have a look at the [Range.NumberFormat Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat).

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(7, "D"), .Cells(7, PasteRange + 4)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` for date format

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple changes needed:

```
Sub Clean()

    Dim tRow As Long: tRow = 5
    Dim bRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian")
        bRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        .Range(.Cells(tRow, "A"), .Cells(bRow, "A")).Copy
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SectorSort")
        .Range("D7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    End With


End Sub
```

Needed to remove `.Activate`

Add the `.` before `Range` and `Cells` because you are in a `With` statement

And also you can just target a single cell when pasting

Comment: Btw. if you don't use `PasteRange` at all you can omit it completely. And it should be `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True`

Comment: You could also do this in one line I believe by just assigning values`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SectorSort").Range("D7:D" & 7 + bRow - tRow).Value = .Range(.Cells(tRow, "A"), Application.Transpose(.Cells(bRow, "A")).Value)
`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian").Activate
```

into

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian")
```

Same for the next With (regarding "SectorSort")